# In Qt Creator FakeVim mode, is there a keyboard shortcut to change to a different split?

Tags: qt-creator, fakevim

I'm using Qt Creator, and I turned on FakeVim mode because I'm used to editing in vim. This mostly works well, but I'm having one issue where I can't find the keyboard shortcut and need to use my mouse (like an animal). I have a big screen and like to set up multiple splits so I can see what is going on in multiple files easily, but I can't find the keyboard shortcut to change which editor split is active. The [manual](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-keyboard-shortcuts.html) says that "Ctrl+E, O" should go to another split, but this isn't working for me (presumably because FakeVim captures the Ctrl+E for the usual vim purposes). Is there a way to change the active split in Qt Creator while using FakeVim mode without taking my fingers off the keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out - treat Qt Creator splits like [vim windows](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#windows). So <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>,  navigates around splits (with <kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>l</kbd> being the usual vim navigation directions). And it appears you can use all the rest of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> commands too.